# dont care condition in digital logic combinational circuit

Tags: circuit-design

[image]

why are we taking dont care condition,in m1,m2,m3,m12,m13,m14 in 8 4-2-1 to bcd converter?I dont get it.

Comment: It looks to me like there is something wrong with the maps.  First, I think the tables should be DCBA and zyxw, for example if you look at the z = D result, it would be correct, and y = CD' + C'D would also be correct.  Having 6 don't care conditions would make sense if it's intended for BCD where only 10 conditions would be used, but the don't cares marked on the maps don't seem to correlate with what I would expect to be unused states (zyxw = 10-15).

Comment: can we take 1-3 and 12-14 as dont cares instead of 10-15??

Comment: Why?  Typical BCD uses 0-9.  Is there more information provided with this example that would suggest why those states can be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

With four bits you can encode 16 possible states. Binary Code Decimal (BCD) can encode 0 to 9. Meaning six of the positions are not used.

The encoder in this case is encoding binairy to graycode. And only 10 positions are used. This can be done arbitrary. I have no explanation why this one is chosen, likely for the logic simplicity.

Comment: then why m1,m2,m3 are being considered in dont care?

Answer (score 0):

When you have neighboring don't-care bits, try to take as many of them as possible to make the resulting logic simpler.
For example, AC'D' uses fewer gates than A**B'**C'D'.